# Changing background color problem in mootools

Tags: javascript, mootools

I have the following css classes:

```
.info {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    display: block;}
.info_edit {
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    padding-left: 15px;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E9E9E9;
 }
.info_wait {
  padding-left: 15px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
display: block; 
background:url(../js/Assets/fbloader.gif) center center no-repeat #fff;
  }
```

I am changing the background color and styles using the following code:

```
function emailEdit() {
    var request = new Request({
        url: '${email_edit}',
        onRequest: function() {
            $('email').set('html','');
            $('email').removeClass('info_edit');
            $('email').addClass('info_wait');
        },
        onSuccess: function(response) {
            $('email').removeClass('info_wait');
            $('email').addClass('info');
            $('email').set('html', response);
                    var myFx = new Fx.Tween('email', {
                        duration: 500,
                        transition: Fx.Transitions.Sine.easeInOut
                    });
                    myFx.start('background-color','#F2F2F2')
                        .chain(function(){
                            myFx.start('background-color','#FFFFFF');
                        }).chain(function(){
                            myFx.start('background-color','#F2F2F2');
                        }).chain(function(){
                            myFx.start('background-color','#FFFFFF');
                        }); 
        }
    }).send();
}
```

In order to attract the user's attention, I have added that animation, but now what happens is if I change the class of the 'email' element using the following code:

```
$('email').removeClass('info');
$('email').addClass('info_edit');
```

the background color remains the same i.e; `#FFFFFF`, but the 'info_edit' class has background-color as '#F2F2F2'

Comment: The color coding already reveals one error: You missed a quote with this line `$('email').addClass('info);` Have you checked with FireBug if there are more errors? Also, might I suggest you put `$('email')` in a variable? That way, if the element ever changes you won't have to change it 6 times and it will not call the `$()` function 6 times.

Comment: thats a typo, in my code firebug shows no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're calling:

```
myFx.start('background-color','#FFFFFF');
```

MooTools is manipulating the inline styles of that element. This type of styling overrides *any* style declared in a class (even if the class is added after the inline style is applied). You can see this using the "style" tab of Firebug or similar when you're inspecting an element.

To get around this, you could set the `background-color` to `null` or `''` to explicitly remove the inline-style for `background-color`:

```
$('email').removeClass('info');
$('email').setStyle("background-color", ''); // <-- Remove inline style
$('email').addClass('info_edit');
```

Comment: myFx.start('background-color',''); did not work, but         myFx.start('background-color',null); did. Thanks.